# deleting an s3 bucket in golang, how to find the user id?

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I have a small piece of golang that creates a bucket on s3, does a few things with it, and in the end, I want to delete that bucket that I created.  But in the [input parameters of DeleteBucket](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3#DeleteBucketInput), it's mandatory to specify the account ID of the bucket owner.

I'm struggling to figure out **programmatically** the account ID used by my own program.  I don't want to hardcode it nor to ask the user to specify it.  I also tried to get the owner of the bucket with GetBucketAcl and friends, but all these also require the account ID.

Any advice on getting the account id?

Comment: `ExpectedBucketOwner` is optional.  You can leave it nil rather than trying to look up the correct value.

Comment: The docs have an example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.DeleteBucket